# Empty Rake -T on old version of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

When I run `rake -T` I get no output:

$ rake -T
$ rake -v
(in /Users/noah/Work/website)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

No matter what I run `rake db:migrate` for example, I always get the don't know how to build task 'whatever'

I'm using ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.8, and rake (0.8.7).

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle exec rake ...` instead?

Comment: @JonathanCairns, I get `Could not locate Gemfile` because there is no bundler associated with this project.

Answer (score 1):

Due to incompatibilities between all the different ruby, rails, rake, etc versions I had to move to Rails 2.3.14.